# Type not asignable (TypeScript 4.1.2)

Tags: typescript, notifications, electron

I'm using this piece of code from an old project (typescript 2) but it's not working with typescript 4.1.2. I'm trying to handle click events on desktop notification from an electron app (renderer process):

```
const nativeNotification = window.Notification;
const ProxyNotification = (title: any, options: any) => {
  const mirrorNotification = new nativeNotification(title, options);
  mirrorNotification.onclick = () => {
     // Handle click event.
  };
};
ProxyNotification.permission = nativeNotification.permission;
ProxyNotification.requestPermission = nativeNotification.requestPermission;
window.Notification = ProxyNotification;
```

The last line throws this error:

> Type '{ (title: string, options?: NotificationOptions): void;
> permission: NotificationPermission; maxActions: number; prototype:
> Notification; requestPermission: (deprecatedCallback?:
> NotificationPermissionCallback) => Promise<...>; }' is not assignable
> to type '{ new (title: string, options?: NotificationOptions):
> Notification; prototype: Notification; readonly maxActions: number;
> readonly permission: NotificationPermission;
> requestPermission(deprecatedCallback?:
> NotificationPermissionCallback): Promise<...>; }'.   Type '{ (title:
> string, options?: NotificationOptions): void; permission:
> NotificationPermission; maxActions: number; prototype: Notification;
> requestPermission: (deprecatedCallback?:
> NotificationPermissionCallback) => Promise<...>; }' provides no match
> for the signature 'new (title: string, options?: NotificationOptions):
> Notification'.

I would appreciate some help to fix it.

Kind regards.

Comment: You were using an arrow function as a constructor somehow?  That doesn't work in any flavor of JS that supports arrow functions natively.  Perhaps this only worked before because your emitted JS downleveled arrow functions to anonymous `function`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you want to extend Native window.Notification.
Here is how I would do this:

```js
const nativeNotification = window.Notification;

class ProxyNotification extends Notification {
        constructor(title: string, options?: NotificationOptions | undefined) {
                super(title, options)
        }
        customMethod() {
                console.log('hello')
        }
        /**
         * Here you can define your own methods and properties
         */
}

window.Notification = ProxyNotification
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. Now, I'm trying to add a listerner and handle click events on those extended notifications. I'm struggling with it, could you help me? I'm sorry I'm currently starting with typeScript.

Comment: @Nameless sure, no problem, just publish your question here, I will take a look

Comment: Just leave here a link to your new question

Comment: I have updated this one. You can see how I overwrote native notifications to capture click events. Now, with the new class to extend native notifications, I'm struggling to make it works. I tried to overwrite addEventListener method or do something similar inside constructor but it isn't working.

Comment: @Nameless you better ask it in new question, because my answer will be incomatible with your question. Context will be lost for other people

Comment: Sure, here is the new ask: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65370936/14850997 . Thank you.