# How to extend native window.Notification to handle click events (TypeScript 4.1.2)

Tags: typescript, notifications, electron

I want to extend native `window.Notification` to handle click events in an `Electron` app (renderer process). I had this working on `TypeScript 2`:

```
const nativeNotification = window.Notification;
const ProxyNotification = (title: any, options: any) => {
  const mirrorNotification = new nativeNotification(title, options);
  mirrorNotification.onclick = (event) => {
    console.log("NOTIFICATION CLICKED!")
  };
};

ProxyNotification.permission = nativeNotification.permission;
ProxyNotification.requestPermission = nativeNotification.requestPermission;
window.Notification = ProxyNotification;
```

In `TypeScript 4` isn't working ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65359425/14850997)). I tried something like this:

```
const nativeNotification = window.Notification;

class ProxyNotification extends Notification {
  constructor(title: string, options?: NotificationOptions | undefined) {
    const mirrornotification = new nativeNotification(title, options);
    mirrornotification.onclick = (event) => {
      console.log("NOTIFICATION CLICKED!")
    };
    super(title, options);
  }
}

window.Notification = ProxyNotification;
```

I also tried to overwrite **onclick** property or **addEventListener** method inside **ProxyNotification** class, but I cannot make it works. Any help will be appreciate.

Kind regards.

Comment: That's part of the official documentation: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/notifications

Comment: Thank you, I know Electron official documentation is good. But this app is a web scrape, I have no control over the renderer process. I use a preload script to make adjustments. So, I'm not generating notifications, I need to capture/overwrite them.

Comment: What exactly don't work in your implementstion? I did not receive any errors in TS playground

Comment: I updated the question. It's not a syntax error. I cannot make it works with this logic. Any ideas to achieve it?